# Initrd regeneration on every installation

Tags: grub2, upgrade, lubuntu

After upgrading to 14.04 and switching to lubuntu I noticed that almost any package installation entails initrd regeneration:

```
$ aptitude reinstall udev
...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
...
```

What is going on?

Comment: Are you sure that happens for _every_ package? It makes sense that it would occur for `full-upgrade`, you're probably upgrading the kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

> After upgrading to 14.04 and switching to lubuntu

Upgrading from what? I haven't noticed it being much more common of late on 14.04 Ubunutu, but maybe that crept up on me, having been staying with the more current version each time.

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs:

> "update-initramfs" is generally called when you install such a package that is potentially capable of configuring your root device. For eg: if you install the package "cryptsetup", no matter if your root device is encrypted or not, the installation of the package would call update-initramfs which will execute the "hook" script installed (when the package was installed).

You'd certainly expect this with a re-install of udev, since the device manager clearly is used early in the whole process.